# Why is Buddhism popular in Eastern Asia compared to South Asia where it originated?

Tags: history, east-asian-buddhism

Buddhism originated in India but from what I understand it's not very big in India and instead more popular in Eastern Asia in countries like Japan, Vietnam, China etc.

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate of existing questions. Please read the linked questions to see if the answers to those questions answer this question too.

Comment: Theravada destroyed Buddhism in South Asia by perverting the teachings into something resembling Hinduism. Where as in East Asia there was no religion similar to Hinduism. Today, the Theravadins continue to pervert the True Dhamma